# Matplotlib: Streamplot arrow position

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, plot

Is there a way to get/set the position of arrows on a streamline plotted with matplotlib's streamplot. I want the arrows to have the same x or y coordinate. So they all appear on one line. I know that the function returns Collection object but I did not succeed in extracting anything meaningful.